# ElasticSearch PHP API: Waiting did not resolve future

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have a strange error when I am **indexing** data. I do like in this **example** :

`https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_indexing_documents.html`

and get that error:

```
GuzzleHttp\\Ring\\Exception\\RingException did not resolve future
```

but index has created. Version of libs is latest.

What could be there? May be should I set a setting to ElasticSearch server? Or should set some a additional param in request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I resolved my problem. Just at first I tried using this php lib without composer autoload because I have my own autoload. As result I started using composer autload.

Answer (score 3):

Had same problem as you with latest ES php api recently. Installed it whole by composer and died on

> GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\RingException: Waiting did not resolve future

while trying any call on api. We dont want to use default composer autoload script beacause of our inhouse autoloader. Main problem was that our autoloader did not load functions from

> React/Promise/functions_include.php

so simple include/require of that file will solve it.

Comment: yes, in the end I have gone to this, but using composer autoload is acceptable for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @zemiak. Actually the same custom autoloader problem is with me too. The problem is resolved once I included the file.